How long is it allowed to block a grpc thread
I have implemented a server-streaming server based on grpc. The grpc::ServerWriteReactor class is used as stream writers. When a remote procedure is called by a client, a reactor is created. The data for is retrieved from a thread-safe queue: in the OnWriteDone method, the next Response is retrieved and passed to the StartWrite method.
The queue is blocking. When there is no data in it, the reading thread (in my case it is the grpc library thread) blocks until data arrives in the queue.
Are there any restrictions on how long a grpc thread can be blocked? Is there some kind of liveness probe inside grpc that, seeing that the thread is blocked, will take some action?

There are no restrictions on the thread usage. gRPC has several threads in the pool and will grow the pool if necessary.

Is there documentation about this somewhere?

On this page https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/best_practices/ there is the following words "Reactions should be fast. Do not do blocking or long-running/heavy weight tasks or sleep. It could impact other RPCs within the process". This contradicts your answer. Where is the truth?

There is no set guideline. It all depends on the application. gRPC uses a thread pool. holding some threads for long processing runs the application into risk of thread starvation when a lot of gRPC is happening.

Is there a way to find out the number of threads in a pool?

It grows and shrinks. This is subject to change soon, as we are switching to new thread pool internally. I don't believe I can give a useful answer at this time :)
